Windows 11 heap_corruption explorer.exe crashing randomly when moving files
I have run into an issue recently where my explorer crashes seemingly randomly when I try moving around files in the file explorer, even sometimes when I'm "idle" not using it. The task bar will freeze up and crash as well as any file explorers will close out. I have added reg keys to output the dump file and have opened in windbg but I'm not sure how to read it to figure out what the problem is.
Pastebin
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Windows crashing the way it suggests a memory problem.  Update your question to include the results testing your memory using the appropriate tools. What you have provided isn't helpful to diagnose your problem, you would need to provide the analysis from WinDBG, in order for us to look at that information.  How you use WInDBG to generate that analysis is well documented.

@Ramhound thanks for the response. Sorry I thought that might've been enough, here is the pastebin link

I just ran a "quick" test on my memory via Lenovo diagnostics and it came back clean. I will run the extended test tonight and report back if nothing is found in the WinDbg result.

The heap corruption is most likely being caused by something other than explorer itself. Take a close look at any shell handlers attached, might try Autoruns from Microsoft ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns ) Disaable any you can to test and if that helps, re-enable them one at a time to see if you can find the culprit.
